# reload the i3 conf in a script

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting, i3

i am writing a script to quick change the mod key of i3

```
conf0="/home/myuser/.config/i3/config"

case "${1}" in
  (alt) key=Mod1 ;;
  (win) key=Mod4 ;;
  (*)   printf "Invalid key: %s\n" "${1}" ; exit 1 ;;
esac

sed -i 's/^\(set $mod\) .*/\1 '"${key}/" "${conf0}" || exit

printf "Changed successfully to %s/%s\n" "${1}" "${key}"
```

but i wont the i3 config to automatically reload at the end of my script. I found xdotool might work but if have to check the current $mod key to be able to reload i3.

How can this? Is awk a goo choice for that?

Please point me in the right direction

Comment: I assume you're talking about sending keystrokes to the app, this doesn't seem like an ideal approach.  A quick google found this which may suggest a better solution is available: https://faq.i3wm.org/question/6505/reload-config-from-bash.1.html

Comment: Sorry thought to over the head, but this is a great solution! This fixed my probem! Thx

Comment: Great, glad it worked. I’ve added it as an answer so the commands are here for any future on lookers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this page](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/6505/reload-config-from-bash.1.html), these commands seem to be available:

```
i3-msg reload
i3-msg restart
```